# Memory fault when inserting output for an std::basic_ostream instantiation in QNX

Tags: c++, qnx

I have the following scenario:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>

class File_ostream final : public std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>
{
};

int main()
{
    const std::string input_file{"file_tests/test.txt.gz"};
    std::ifstream ifs{input_file, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary};

    File_ostream file_os{};

    file_os << ifs.rdbuf(); // Memory fault (core dumped) 
}
```

My program always crashes when inserting output to `file_os` and creates a core dump.

The code works fine in Linux but not in QNX :\

Do you have any explanation? hint?

Comment: Is it on purpose that the constructor doesn't do anything with its argument `os`?

Comment: @sebrockm I have the same problem with or without the constructor. I will update the code sample.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? `basic_ostream` doesn't have a default constructor. Any standard compliant compiler will not compile the provided code snippet.

Comment: @sebrockm in Linux I use g++ and for QNX I use QCC. Both v 5.4.0

Comment: OK, strange. I verified that gcc indeed compiles it, so does clang. msvc correctly cannot compile it. Anyway, if it compiles, your `basic_ostream` instance will be in a not documented, not standardized state. That might explain the crash. Try the correct constructor: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream

Comment: @sebrockm Thanks a lot. I have followed your instructions and solved the problem. You can post it as a solution if you want, and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the default constructor of `basic_ostream` which, by the standard, does not exist. I have no idea why g++ and QCC compile your code successfully, but they shouldn't.

Anyway, using non standardized functions reveals non standardized behavior, in your case a crash. I don't know if the correct usage of the default constructor is documented anywhere in the gcc docs, but just avoiding it, and using [the correct constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream) instead, should solve your issue.